# Unable to register mirrored Deployer Capabilities

Tags: microservices, discovery-service, discovery

I'm trying to setup mirrored publishing in our production Web 8.5 environment so that content is published both to our production broker, as well as our fail-over broker but am unable to register two deployer capabilities.

I was able to register (and successfully publish content to) a single Deployer capability, however when I try to setup mirrored publishing I am getting an error when I run the discovery-registration utility.

**Discovery Service Role:**

```
<Role Name="DeployerCapability" Strategy="MIRROR" >
<Urls>
    <Url Value="https://www.my-domain.com/sdl/httpupload" />
    <Url Value="https://www-fo.my-domain.com/sdl/httpupload" />
</Urls>
<Property Name="encoding" Value="UTF-8"/>
```

I am able to hit both of the endpoints via Postman, and if I register either service as follows things work fine:

```
<Role Name="DeployerCapability" Url="https://www.my-domain.com/sdl/httpupload" >
```

I'm also able to hit the discovery service with a successful response. Like I said, publishing works fine when I setup a single deployer capability - but I can't register two for some reason.

When I try to register the capabilities via the role definition above with a mirror strategy, the discovery service is throwing errors:

> 2019-12-12 14:47:03,451 ERROR ODataRendererActor - Error during datasource access: 'Unexpected error while creating entity 'DeployerCapability{id='DefaultDeployer', lastUpdateTime=null, strategy='MIRROR', uri='https://www.my-domain.com/sdl/httpupload', uris='[DestinationURL{uri='https://www.my-domain.com/sdl/httpupload', destinationName='null'}, DestinationURL{uri='https://www-fo.my-domain.com/sdl/httpupload', destinationName='null'}]', ExtensionProperties='[KeyValue{key='encoding', value='UTF-8'}]'}'. null'
>   com.sdl.odata.api.processor.datasource.ODataDataSourceException: Unexpected error while creating entity 'DeployerCapability{id='DefaultDeployer', lastUpdateTime=null, strategy='MIRROR', uri='https://www.my-domain.com/sdl/httpupload', uris='[DestinationURL{uri='https://www.my-domain.com/sdl/httpupload', destinationName='null'}, DestinationURL{uri='https://www-fo.my-domain.com/sdl/httpupload', destinationName='null'}]', ExtensionProperties='[KeyValue{key='encoding', value='UTF-8'}]'}'. null
>       at com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.TridionConfigDataSource.create(TridionConfigDataSource.java:219)
>       at com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.TridionConfigDataSource.create(TridionConfigDataSource.java:149)
>
> 2019-12-12 14:47:03,449 ERROR TridionConfigDataSource - Unexpected exception while creating entity
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>       at com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.DestinationURL.hashCode(DestinationURL.java:58)
>       at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339)
>       at java.util.HashMap.containsKey(HashMap.java:596)
>       at com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.TridionConfigItemMapper.convertODataEntityToDS(TridionConfigItemMapper.java:136)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I dug into the code and it appears as though while it says the **DestinationName** is optional, I was getting a null pointer in the code on it.

> DestinationName   The name of this particular Capability instance (optional)

I added a DestinationName for both of the capabilities, and then tried to register all of the capabilities which was successful.

```
<Role Name="DeployerCapability" Strategy="MIRROR" >
<Urls>
    <Url DestinationName="Production" Value="https://www.my-domain.com/sdl/httpupload" />
    <Url DestinationName="Failover" Value="https://www-fo.my-domain.com/sdl/httpupload" />
</Urls>
<Property Name="encoding" Value="UTF-8"/>
```

We are on a recent cumulative **hotfix CD_8.5.0.16047**.

Comment: Glad that you have the issue resolved. Please accept the answer so the question becomes closed.